# Flaggers of Stack Exchange, please let this one slide

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

#### Do you want uncountable wealth?

Famed globally, **Anthony Gardiner** demonstrates skyhigh statesmanship, specializing openly on politics. Absolutely thoughtful, occasionally confrontational, satisfaction shall fulfil requests!

<sub>is a genuine puzzle not an ad</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you

> take the first letter of the first word, second letter of the second, and so on, *wrapping around when necessary*...
>
>  [image: grid where each row is a word from the sentence, repeated; the diagonal is highlighted]
>  it spells out **Do not flag this post for this...**, which is a sentence completed by the small "is a genuine puzzle not an ad".